# Wrong column highlight on lines containing references or links

Tags: neovim, highlight, cursor

I've recently taken up nvim and came accross a weird issue.

I've turned on cursor position highlighting for both lines and columns (`set cursorline` and `set cursorcolumn`), and usually it works as expected:

[image]

However, when navigating within lines which contains links (e.g. in :Tutor), while the column and line highlight work fine, the cursor lags behind:

[image]

I have the following plugins installed:

- nvim-lspconfig
- cmp-nvim-lsp
- cmp-buffer
- cmp-path
- cmp-cmdline
- nvim-cmp
- nvim-web-devicons
- nvim-tree.lua
- lualine.nvim (with eviline-config)
- arm-syntax-vim

EDIT: I've disabled my init.vim (renamed it) and even with the default config the issue is still there: after the cursor reaches the end of the link, pressing 'l' a few times does nothing, the cursor remains there. After pressing 'l' more times the cursor eventually reaches the next character.

EDIT2: This also seems to happen with references or bold formatting.

Comment: I can reproduce with nvim 0.6.1. It looks like it's a bug of `cursorcolumn` when the syntax file has some concealed elements ([`:h conceal`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/syntax.html#conceal)) maybe it's worth creating a bug on neovim issue tracker if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: So far, the most similar issue I've found is https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/16447. I'll consider creating a new bug if I can't find anything else.